# How do i capture mysql triggers and stored procedures in my vb.net application?

Tags: mysql, wpf, vb.net, stored-procedures, triggers

Hey i need some help here, i am developing a vb.net desktop application using visual Studio 2010 and mysql v5.5 whose database will be located in a main server hence the applications will have to communicate with the the database to get/post information.

My problem however is that, i want my applications to have a real time update of the database content such that if user1 updates the database, it immediately reflects that in user2's application. I have read articles that recommend use of triggers and Stored Procedures in mysql syntax to do this but i have no idea how this will work.

I have a table called 'Store' , when a user enters an item in table store, i'd like the application to know it and update the Item and its contents in a listbox or datagrid.

How do i capture these events in my vb.net code?

I hope i am clear enough, if not please ask. All your suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Where do you add items to the table? Is it from your application?

Comment: Check this out: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120805164032AAIHvn4

Comment: Yeah I add items from a form in the application

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to solve the problem would be to periodically get the records from the server and update the local list appropriately. On your client application you could store the last time the list was updated, and send that as a parameter when you do the get and get all the items that were created after that time (that way you only get new items).

Another possible solution would be to have a client register with the server application (so the server keeps track of all the clients) and when you create a new record you send that new record to all the clients, which would be listening for that event.

It's sort of hard to say what the 'best' approach is in your situation. How is your code designed (what's the architecture)? Are connections between the client and server applications persistent? Is there a server application that your client application talks to or is each client directly talking to the database?

Comment: I had thought of that but i was trying to find a way to ease network traffic by the applications furthermore it is an inventory application so when users enter data from different clients at different(almost similar) times, if not synchronised then a duplicate entry might occur causing an exception to be thrown. In my application, i do a query once and store the results in an array where it will be used throughout the application, yes each client communicates directly with the database.

Comment: I think your best bet is to use polling to refresh the data in your situation, actually I don't think there is a way around it.
I don't believe there is a way to listen to database triggers.

The only other solution, as stated above, is if you had an intermediate server application that could handle requests appropriately, like all create requests get sent to the app server to handle, and then send a response back to all connected clients (if the create was successful). This seems like a lot more work though.